# Non HTTPS URL in Identity Server 4 Discovery Document

Tags: identityserver4

I hosted IdentityServer4 on IIS. Endpoint URL's are having HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I already tried forwardheaders method. But doesn't seems to have any effect. We have SSL offloading. Is that the reason? Is there any different solution for that?

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Comment: which version of Identity Server 4 are you running? which .NET Core version?

Comment: .NET 5.0 & Identity Server 4.1.2 I am using the solution from the Identity Server GitHub samples. I could run that without problem on IIS express locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In older versions (< 4.0) it was possible to set `IdentityServerOptions.PublicOrigin` including a fixed scheme (since some people seem to have troubles to get the forwarded headers working). Even me used this in an older project.

For the newer versions (4.x+)

If you are sure it will be https and you are sure what the public domain is you can follow [this issue on Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535). There leastpriviledge offers:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin("https://yourdomain.com");
    //ctx.Request.Scheme = "https"; // direct approach
    await next();
});
```

According to the information given within the issue this should do the same.

Comment: yes, I have tried this too. It's still giving me http urls

Comment: hm... have you had disabled the forwarded headers when you tried this? (to prevent the request.scheme to be altered afterwards)?

Comment: When I log value from baseForwardOptions.Value.ForwardedHeaders I get XForwardedFor, XForwardedProto

Comment: I think I made mistake in deployment. This solution is working. Marking it.

Comment: Legend! I been struggling to sort this on an old Identity Server 3 product we have. This PublicOrigin option sorted it for me.

Answer (score 4):

So the new version / library is Duende 6.2.3, the method SetIdentityServerOrigin has been marked obsolete (as with most of the extension methods within Duende.IdentityServer.Extensions.HttpContextExtensions. It now recommends using IServiceUrls.Option, which I've implemented as such:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>{
       if (ctx != null)
            {
                ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServerUrls>().Origin = "[NEW URL]";
            }
       await next();
        });
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was hung up on this for like a day. It worked for me, and notably I added it near the beginning of the build pipeline, before the IdentityServer stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Richmond's approach, setting `GetRequiredService<IServerUrls>().Origin`, worked for me (important to put it **before** `UseIdentityServer`).

**However**, if the problem is caused by a reverse proxy, changing the origin is a workaround. Duende have documented that scenario here:

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/deployment/proxies/

The op's original `UseForwardedHeaders` approach was correct. Possible reasons it was wasn't having any effect:

- UseForwardedHeaders needs to be at the start of the pipeline
- The reverse proxy iteslf needs to be configured to send the "forwarded for" headers - MS explain how to do this for nginx, etc, in the Duende link above.